# Does styling the scrollbar affect UX?

Tags: usability, gui-design, human-interface-guideline, scrollbars

What's the standard on styling scrollbars? Do you only apply it on panels within your application and leave the window scroll bars to a default? Does messing with scrollbar styles affect user experience and ease of access?

Answer (score 1):

Skinning any standard UI Elements reduces usability. Why not using the forms, radios buttons, checkboxes, scrollbars etc. the user is used to from his favorite browser or device?

1. Users are used to native UI.
2. The native UI is always faster and it works.
3. Users don't have to learn new UI elements.
4. The effort is often to high to develop good working UI elements.

This is really something designers should leave their hands off. It's not their business!

Comment: I disagree on this, because it often breaks the design for the rest of the content. Specially if the scroll bars are for a small scrollable block in the middle of the page. I really think CSS standards should be extended to support this. It makes no sense to have some GUI elements styleable and others not.